# triming an "input field"

Tags: javascript, input, trim

I'm trying to make a form validation function and I am using `forEach` on the `input` fields.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(input){
    input.addEventListener("blur", function (){

        const inputT = input.value.trim();

        if(inputT.validity.valueMissing){
            // e_space is the place where errors are displayed
            if(e_space){
                e_space.textContent = "This field must not be empty.";
                input.classList.add("b-r");
            }
            input.classList.add("input-red");
        }else{
            e_space.textContent = "";
            input.classList.remove("b-r");
        }
}
```

The problem (I think) is that I'm working with fields and not the content of the fields ie: `input.addEventListener` etc. so I can't trim them.

As shown in the example above I tried creating a variable `inputT` with the content of the field `input.value`, triming it and passing it on to the function. Now I get an error: *inputT.validity is undefined*

Could anyone recommend a way to trim the value of the input field and then run the validity check?

Thank you.

Comment: `inputT` is a string, not the element. Consider using more precise variable names to avoid these sorts of problems

Comment: yes, it's a variable. Sorry, I don't understand the point you are trying to make

Comment: in your `if` - you use `inputT.validity` which isn't a part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this snippet of code

```
const inputT = input.value.trim();
```

the trim function returns a new string, not an HTML element or (input element)
so the new string does not have a "validity" property.

then update this code:

```
 const inputT = input.value.trim();
    if(inputT.validity.valueMissing){...}
```

with this:

```
input.value = input.value.trim();
if(input.validity.valueMissing){...}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `.validity` property exists on input elements, not trimmed strings.

You'll need to first update the value to the trimmed value, then check the validity on the input field.

For example:

```
input.addEventListener("blur", function (){

        input.value = input.value.trim();

        if(input.validity.valueMissing){
           // ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.